# Source another shell script relative to current script path without $0

Tags: bash, shell

I wonder if there's a good way to source another shell script without $(basename "$0") solution, since sometimes "$0" is not set.

For exmaple "$0" would be "-sh" for login shell.

There's same problem with regard to cwd solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this expression to find out the directory of the parent Bash script:

```
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

Then you can call your script like this:

```
cd $dir; source ./other_script
```

or

```
source $dir/other_script
```

See this related post: [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within?rq=1)

Comment: What about non-bash solution? Is there a POSIX shell solutions?

Comment: I didn't find a POSIX solution.  If I were to do it, I will check  the output of `$(dirname $0)`.  If it is an absolute path, just use that dir.  If it is a relative path, use `$PWD/$(dirname $0)`.  Otherwise, traverse `$PATH` and look for `$0` in each directory.

Comment: This still won't work, as sometimes $0 is the -sh, which is irrelevant to any path.

Comment: That could be simplified into `dir="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"`, which removes the external call to dirname as well as the two subshells this answer creates.